# How to fix 'Error: unmatched pseudo-class :flex' in cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm using node.js and cheerio.
When trying to find an element inside a selector I get the error 'unmatched pseudo-class :flex'

```
const $ = cheerio.load(data)
const name = $('#__next > div.w-full.py-10.flex.flex-col.items-center.space-y-3 > div:nth-child(1) > div.flex.hidden.md\:flex.w-full.items-center.gap-5.md\:gap-2 > div.flex.w-64.items-center.gap-3 > h2')
```

I've hear the same thing happens with :first which can be replaced with .first() but i'm not sure what I should do with flex.

Comment: If you have example HTML data, please update your question with it.